# what is the difference of Normal distribution with link function log and lognormal distribution?

Tags: logging, glm, normal-distribution

what is the difference of Normal distribution with link function log and lognormal distribution ?

In the context of GLM modeling, I attempted to comprehend the difference between a Normal distribution with a logarithmic link function and a Lognormal distribution because mathematically, both distributions exhibit similar forms.

for example:
Normal distribution with link function log:
Y=ln(B0+B1x1+B2x2)

lognormal distribution
Y= ln(x)